# Ambiguous Outer Joins?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join, disambiguation

I am getting the following error message...

"The SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambiguous outer joins. To force one of the joins to be performed first, create a separate query that performs the first join and then include that query in your SQL statement."

HOW CAN I FIX THIS???  If i replace the "LEFT JOIN" with "INNER JOIN" the bug goes away but the desired operation is not accomplished.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT route.productfam, 
       facility.location, 
       asmlines.line, 
       tableconsolidate2.sumofyr, 
       tableconsolidate2.sumofyr0, 
       tableconsolidate2.sumofyr1, 
       tableconsolidate2.sumofyr2, 
       tableconsolidate2.sumofyr3, 
       tableconsolidate2.sumofyr4, 
       tableconsolidate2.sumofyr5, 
       route.cycletime, 
       route.numperprod, 
       facilitylines.operationalhr, 
       [18months].[month 1], 
       [18months].[month 2], 
       [18months].[month 3], 
       [18months].[month 4], 
       [18months].[month 5], 
       [18months].[month 6], 
       [18months].[month 7], 
       [18months].[month 8], 
       [18months].[month 9], 
       [18months].[month 10], 
       [18months].[month 11], 
       [18months].[month 12], 
       [18months].[month 13], 
       [18months].[month 14], 
       [18months].[month 15], 
       [18months].[month 16], 
       [18months].[month 17], 
       [18months].[month 18] 
FROM   ((productfamily 
         INNER JOIN (facility 
                     INNER JOIN tableconsolidate2 
                             ON facility.location = 
                                tableconsolidate2.[build plant]) 
                 ON productfamily.productfamily = 
                    tableconsolidate2.[prod series]) 
        LEFT JOIN 18months 
               ON ( facility.location = [18months].location ) 
                  AND ( productfamily.productfamily = [18months].[item type] )) 
       INNER JOIN ((asmlines 
                    INNER JOIN facilitylines 
                            ON asmlines.line = facilitylines.line) 
                   INNER JOIN route 
                           ON asmlines.line = route.line) 
               ON ( productfamily.productfamily = route.productfam ) 
                  AND ( facility.location = facilitylines.facility ) 

GROUP BY route.productfam, facility.location, Asmlines.line, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr0, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr1, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr2, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr3, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr4, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr5, route.cycletime, route.numperprod, facilitylines.operationalhr, [18Months].[Month 1], [18Months].[Month 2], [18Months].[Month 3], [18Months].[Month 4], [18Months].[Month 5], [18Months].[Month 6], [18Months].[Month 7], [18Months].[Month 8], [18Months].[Month 9], [18Months].[Month 10], [18Months].[Month 11], [18Months].[Month 12], [18Months].[Month 13], [18Months].[Month 14], [18Months].[Month 15], [18Months].[Month 16], [18Months].[Month 17], [18Months].[Month 18], route.productfam

ORDER BY facility.location;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit... I didnt know how to put it in that code box.  :D

Comment: I think you should give an alias to each table and subquery

Comment: I have read several articles about this: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=137883.                                                                                                                                            I have tried applying this to my query but cant successfully adapt this approach

Comment: Can't even make a start on this without schemas and an unambiguous spec for what you want to end up with. Start with you innermost join, write a query, give it a name. Then go up one level write another query that joins to the one you just did, give it name. Keep going until you end up with what you want. Then you can look look at changing it to sub queries, if you feel the need. Bear in mind some queries might be siblings as opposed to children. Best of luck.

Comment: The Access SQL parser is not very advanced. As you only have one outer join, putting it after all the inner joins is more likely to be understood. I have adopted the habit of putting all the open parentheses before the first table name in the FROM clause and a closing parenthesis after each ON clause except the last - this way it's easier to read and to edit manually than the sort of mess that the query builder can produce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create a query that contains a LEFT JOIN and an INNER JOIN, Access may not be able to determine which join operation to perform first. Because the results are different depending on whether the left join or the inner join is performed first, Access displays an error message:

To correct this error, you must modify the query so that it is clear which join to perform first.

Consequently solution can be achieved by splitting this into two queries and then joining them in and additional query.

Query 1:

```
SELECT route.productfam, facility.location, Asmlines.line, [18Months].[Month 1], [18Months].[Month 2], [18Months].[Month 3], [18Months].[Month 4], [18Months].[Month 5], [18Months].[Month 6], [18Months].[Month 7], [18Months].[Month 8], [18Months].[Month 9], [18Months].[Month 10], [18Months].[Month 11], [18Months].[Month 12], [18Months].[Month 13], [18Months].[Month 14], [18Months].[Month 15], [18Months].[Month 16], [18Months].[Month 17], [18Months].[Month 18], route.cycletime, route.numperprod, facilitylines.operationalhr
FROM (facility INNER JOIN (ProductFamily INNER JOIN 18Months ON ProductFamily.productfamily = [18Months].[Item Type]) ON facility.location = [18Months].Location) INNER JOIN ((Asmlines INNER JOIN facilitylines ON Asmlines.line = facilitylines.line) INNER JOIN route ON Asmlines.line = route.line) ON (ProductFamily.productfamily = route.productfam) AND (facility.location = facilitylines.facility)
GROUP BY route.productfam, facility.location, Asmlines.line, [18Months].[Month 1], [18Months].[Month 2], [18Months].[Month 3], [18Months].[Month 4], [18Months].[Month 5], [18Months].[Month 6], [18Months].[Month 7], [18Months].[Month 8], [18Months].[Month 9], [18Months].[Month 10], [18Months].[Month 11], [18Months].[Month 12], [18Months].[Month 13], [18Months].[Month 14], [18Months].[Month 15], [18Months].[Month 16], [18Months].[Month 17], [18Months].[Month 18], route.cycletime, route.numperprod, facilitylines.operationalhr, route.productfam
ORDER BY facility.location;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT route.productfam, facility.location, Asmlines.line, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr0, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr1, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr2, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr3, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr4, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr5, route.cycletime, route.numperprod, facilitylines.operationalhr
FROM (ProductFamily INNER JOIN (facility INNER JOIN tableconsolidate2 ON facility.location = tableconsolidate2.[Build Plant]) ON ProductFamily.productfamily = tableconsolidate2.[Prod Series]) INNER JOIN ((Asmlines INNER JOIN facilitylines ON Asmlines.line = facilitylines.line) INNER JOIN route ON Asmlines.line = route.line) ON (ProductFamily.productfamily = route.productfam) AND (facility.location = facilitylines.facility)
GROUP BY route.productfam, facility.location, Asmlines.line, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr0, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr1, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr2, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr3, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr4, tableconsolidate2.SumOfyr5, route.cycletime, route.numperprod, facilitylines.operationalhr, route.productfam
ORDER BY facility.location;
```

Query 3:

```
Query 1 LEFT JOIN Query 2
```

Comment: Thanks, You have to wait 24hrs. before accepting your own answer.

Comment: Damn never noticed it was you. You'll get a hat for that.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/video-fix-the-ambiguous-outer-join-error-c36948dc-c481-48c6-809d-38427e9ffdd7