# Cannot view the SQL portion of a query in ACCESS?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am currently working on a project of replacing our old access database queries, but on one of them I am not able to view the actual SQL View.

Does anyone know a way to force the view or to export it somehow?

Error causing problem:

```
The SQL statement could not be executed because it contains ambiguous outer joins.
```

[image]

Note that I can view the Design View without issue but when I right click on the tab and select SQL View is when I get the error.

I did attempt what @LeeMac mentioned below but same error occurs:

[image]

EDIT:

This question is not like [Ambiguous Outer Joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644836/ambiguous-outer-joins)
The OP on that question can actually see and edit their SQL.
My issues is that I cannot see or edit the SQL as the SQL View wont open.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ambiguous Outer Joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644836/ambiguous-outer-joins)

Comment: @June7 No. The question is how can I get the SQL View to work or get an export of the SQL Code as I am not able to see it. Currently I have no way of actually seeing the SQL Statement. I need to be able to see the SQL Statement to copy it out.

Comment: I don't think can resolve this issue with existing query. Follow suggestion in linked question to rebuild query as two objects. Unfortunately, if there are subqueries involved and you don't know what those SQL statements are, could be SOL.

Comment: @June7 That is not possible as I do not have the original SQL. That is the reason I need to be able to see the SQL View.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I have the same issue, did you manage to solve it somehow in the end?

Comment: @Karura91 We never did figure this one out. I had to rebuild the query from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Try executing the following VBA code from the Immediate Window (accessible using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) in the VBA IDE (open the IDE using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>):

```
?CurrentDb.QueryDefs("YourQuery").SQL
```

Replace `YourQuery` with the name of your query.

This should print the SQL code which comprises your query - you can then analyse the SQL to determine the cause of the error.

---

It's odd this error would arise when merely viewing the SQL content of the query definition.

It makes me think that the query is perhaps referencing a crosstab subquery which is actually the cause of the error, but which needs to be evaluated in order for MS Access to determine the columns available when viewing the design of the query in question.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I have updated my answer with some additional thoughts - I'm clutching at straws with this one though.

Comment: I find it odd as well. Why can it not just show me the query built instead of trying to execute something. My guess is because this was built using the design view then this query likely never worked and was just left in as something to fix later but never did. I still like your VBA. I will be using is for other things down the road.

Comment: Then is the query used anywhere? Maybe you should just delete it?

Comment: Try assigning a the DAO.Database object: `Set db = CurrentDb` then run `Debug.Print db.QueryDefs("YourQuery").SQL`

Comment: @HansUp. It let me import it but I get the same issue of not being able to go to SQL View. Thanks though. Was worth a shot.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Working on my theory that the query references a malformed subquery, does every other query in your database run successfully?

Comment: @LeeMac as far as I can tell yes. I have no way to test this query tho. No errors come up when this query is run within access as the tool is used today at my work. So maybe its skipped in the code but I do not see `resume on error` anywhere in the VBA so it must be running.

Comment: @Mike-SMT you said you can open in design view. I'd suggest open it in design view, make a new query by replicating what objects and fields are in the corrupted query and save it and check if the new query allows you into SQL mode.

Comment: @krishKM I will give that a try when I get into work today.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
hit ctrl-g, and from immediate window type in this:

```
saveastext acQuery,"Name of query","c:\test\mysql.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Access ordinarily doesn't allow you to  save invalid queries, so it's strange you somehow got into this situation in the first place.

If you can copy the query, you can easily get to the SQL by changing the query to a passthrough query, either through the GUI or through VBA:

```
Dim q As DAO.QueryDef
Set q = CurrentDb.QueryDefs!Query1
q.Connect = "ODBC;"
Debug.Print q.SQL
```

Passthrough queries are not validated, so you can freely read and write anything you want as SQL in it.

Note that this is irreversible when done through VBA. You can only change it back to a normal query once you made the SQL valid again. If you do it through the GUI, you can just not save it, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the issue was that i had a subquery that calculated fields but did not actually have a table in it.  for example it would calculate first and last day of last month which is 2 calculated fields, then it was the first query in a series of queries that were built off it and the last one wouldnt resolve sql as original poster indicated also gave the ambiguous join message as well as query needs input table (which was that first subquery).  i put a table with 1 record in it but didnt use the record and it worked.... so it just a needs a table in it.