# Cannot access SQL view of Query object

Tags: ms-access

In one of my working project I need to migrate an old application with an access database.
In this database there is a query object i'd need to access, however when I try to display the SQL view of the object I have the error:

[image]

And I cannot access the content of it in order to fix the error or simply getting it for the sake of migrating it. It's worth noting that the design view works and also the sql statement

```
select * from qry_name;
```

I found a question with essentially the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59059121/cannot-view-the-sql-portion-of-a-query-in-access) and tried already all the propositions there but unfortunately without any luck.

So, how can I get the SQL content? Is there any way? Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you.

Edit:

for further clarification even the statement:

```
?Currentdb.QueryDefs("qry_name").SQL
```

leads to the same popup error at runtime.

Comment: In the VBA Editor's "Immediate Window" try `Application.SaveAsText acQuery, "qry_name", "C:\path\to\qry_name.txt"`

Comment: @GordThompson thank you for your comment.
This produces a file but I am unsure how to reinterpret it in order to rewrite the query.
For example: 
When I look at the joins, there is a Flag field which I do not understand to what it refers, as in :
    LeftTable ="MyTable1"
    RightTable ="MyTable2"
    Expression ="MyTable1.[MyField] = MyTable2.[MyField]"
    Flag =3
What would flag be? The type of join? I was unable to find any documentation on it.

Comment: `Application.SaveAsText` is an undocumented feature and is not really intended to be used by us mere mortals. However it can be helpful in a difficult situation, as it sounds like you are facing. As for the join flag, `Flag=1` is `INNER JOIN`, `Flag=2` is `LEFT JOIN`, and `Flag=3` is `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you, I guess the only choice is to rewrite this query starting from the content generated with `Application.SaveAsText`

Answer (score 0):

Write the following in the debug window:

```
?Currentdb.QueryDefs("qry_name").SQL
```

Comment: I did it already but I have the same error message.

Comment: Test importing the query from another Access database.

Comment: Tried that already, but I still have the same error message